# Android: How come my ListView style gets removed when List Item is scrolled off screen

Tags: android, listview, scroll, listitem

Currently, I have a custom list adapter that has some logic that hide/show a certain ImageView in a row depending on a variable.

Initially, the logic works when the app first launches. (ImageView is hidden/shown accordingly).

But once I scroll the screen up and down, eventually, all the row's ImageView is hidden forever.

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

here is my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PostHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new PostHolder();
            holder.postThumb = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.post_Thumb);
            holder.postComments = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.post_comments);
            holder.postInfo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle);
            holder.postScore = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.post_score);
            holder.postTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.postThumbHolder = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.post_Thumb_holder);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (PostHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> post = data.get(position);

        if(post.get("thumbnail").equals("default") || post.get("thumbnail").equals("self")){
            holder.postThumbHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.postComments.setText(post.get("comments"));
        holder.postInfo.setText(post.get("info"));
        holder.postScore.setText(post.get("score"));
        holder.postTitle.setText(post.get("title"));

        return row;
    }


    static class PostHolder
    {
        LinearLayout postThumbHolder;
        ImageView postThumb;
        TextView postComments;
        TextView postScore;
        TextView postTitle;
        TextView postInfo;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set visibility `View.VISIBLE` to `postThumbHolder` somewhere. In the else block of your 
`if (post.get...`
clause.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with how android makes the background of the list items into bitmaps as soon as you start scrolling. To make sure your image views are visible after scrolling you must also set that property everytime the adapters getView is called do this in the else part of your variable check

```
if(post.get("thumbnail").equals("default") || post.get("thumbnail").equals("self")){
        holder.postThumbHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
        holder.postThumbHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```